# Populating a struct using a function in c

Tags: c, struct

Please somebody help me when I use a function to populate my structure i get diffrent values from what i entered I have been stocked here for a while please somebody help me

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    typedef struct myEMP
     {
        char *empName[20];
        int *empID;
        float *NofHworked;
        int *payRate;
     }myEMP;
     char *Names;

     myEMP getInfo(myEMP 
    employee) {

        printf("Name:");
        
   
  strcpy(employee.empName,fgets( 
    &Names,20,stdin)  );

        printf("ID :");
        
   scanf("%d",&employee.empID);

        printf("No of hours 
    worked :");
        
  scanf("%f",&employee.NofHworked);

        printf("Pyrate :");
        scanf("%d",&employee.payRate);

        return employee;

}



    int main(){

      int N;
 
      myEMP *empINFO;


    getInfo(*empINFO);

    printf("Name \t Id  \t 
    hours \t  payrate \n" );
    printf("%s \t %d \t %.2f \t 
    %d",empINFO- 
    >empName,empINFO- 
    >empID,empINFO- 
    >NofHworked,empINFO- 
    >payRate);
    return 0;
    }
```

I tried runing the code with
 `name: John Doe Id :01 No of hours worked : 06 Payrate :25`

This is what I get
 `Name: â-#[|ìv  Id: -1961038717 Hours: 0.00 Payrate:-1065106551`

I dont know what to do since i am new to c somebody please help

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple issues with your code: The first one is that your code is very hard to read because it is not indented properly. I took the liberty to indent it for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct myEMP {
    char* empName[20];
    int* empID;
    float* NofHworked;
    int* payRate;
} myEMP;

char* Names;

myEMP getInfo(myEMP employee) {
    printf("Name:");
    strcpy(employee.empName, fgets(&Names, 20, stdin));

    printf("ID :");
    scanf("%d", &employee.empID);

    printf("No of hours worked :");
    scanf("%f", &employee.NofHworked);

    printf("Pyrate :");
    scanf("%d", &employee.payRate);

    return employee;
}

int main() {
    int N;

    myEMP* empINFO;

    getInfo(*empINFO);

    printf("Name \t Id  \t hours \t  payrate \n");

    printf("%s \t %d \t %.2f \t %d",empINFO->empName, empINFO->empID, empINFO->NofHworked, empINFO->payRate);

    return 0;
}
```

The second thing is: You should decide on the signature of the function `getInfo`. IMHO, there are two possibilities:

1. Use `void getInfo(myEMP* employee)` as signature.
2. Use `myEMP getInfo()` as signature.

The first one will modify the employee which is stored at the memory address you provide, whereas the second one will return a new employee.

If you really want to use the function you have now, you have to improve your `main` function at least with regard to the following two points:

1. `malloc` the memory for `empINFO`.
2. Use the return value that `getInfo` provides.

However, I suggest redesigning the `getInfo` function.

Please note that I have not tested your code, so there is a good chance that there are even more issues.